# How can maximizing $x^T A x$ where $A$ is positive semi-definite be reduced to maximizing $trace(x^T A x)$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace

Suppose $A$ is a given matrix of shape $n \times n$, and $x$ is some unknown matrix of shape $n \times m$, the objective is

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
& \max_x  x^T A x  \\
\text{subject to } & \lambda_i(A) \ge 0 \text{ for all } 1 \le i \le n \\
& \|x_i\|_2 = 1 \text{where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $x$}
\end{array}
$$

where the objective is a $m \times m$ matrix.

My question is can it be reduced to

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
& \max_x  tr(x^T A x)  \\
\text{subject to } & \lambda_i(A) \ge 0 \text{ for all } 1 \le i \le n \\
& \|x_i\|_2 = 1  \text{where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $x$}
\end{array}
$$

where the objective is now a scalar.

This question came up as I was learning [Fisher's discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Fisher.27s_linear_discriminant) in the multi-class setting, where the objective is to find a matrix $W$ to transform $X$ onto a low-dimensional space so that the between-class covariance is maximized and the within-class covariance is minimized. And most books give the following criterion,

$$
\max_W \frac{tr(W^T S_b W)}{tr(W^T S_w W)}
$$

where $S_b$ is the between-class scatter matrix, and $S_w$ is the within-class scatter. I believe the scatter matrix is used here instead of the estimate of covariance matrix is because they only differ by a positive constant term.

But I don't understand why we can formulate the criterion using trace when we want to maximize a matrix. In other words, I don't know the proof of this reduction.

**UPDATE**: What I've tried: In the context of Fisher's discriminant analysis, I think maximizing a covariance matrix directly amounts to maximizing the Frobenius norm of that matrix, because we want everything to covariate as much as possible, every elements in that matrix should be large in absolute value. But this is not rigorous enough to my liking. Even if it's correct, it only lead to

$$
\max_x x^T A x \iff \max_x \|x^T A x\|_F \iff \max_x \sqrt{tr(x^T A^T x x^T A x)}
$$

Comment: For $X^TAX$ to be defined, if $X$ has shape $n\times m$ and $A$ has shape $n\times p$, then you must have $p=n$, that is, $A$ must be square. Moreover, $X^TAX$ has shape $m\times m$, what does it mean to maxmize it? Let's imagine for a moment that we can give it some meaning, what happens if we multiply $X$ by a constant?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, $A$ is square here since it's positive semidefinite, I'll edit it to say the shape is $n \times n$. I think the meaning in the context of Fisher's discriminant analysis should be maximizing the Frobenius norm. Please see my updates.

Comment: But then you can make the Frobenius norm arbitrarily large by multiplying $X$ by a large constant (when you maximize with vector $x$, you usually require $||x||=1$ to avoid this, what here?)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut oh, that's right. I was trying to formulate a problem in its own right instead of in the context of Fisher's discriminant analysis (FDA).  In FDA $\|x\| = 1$ is not needed because both denominator and nominator have $W$.

Comment: The question is: How do you maximize a matrix? What's your metric at all?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz In the context of FDA, I think maximizing a matrix amounts to maximizing the Frobenius norm of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I just came into the similar problem of maximize a Frobenius norm as follows( with one more constraint about **zero-mean** data ):

Given a set of zero-mean data, i.e., $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$, whose covariance matrix is $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{\boldsymbol{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$, we have a chance to add two outliers, i.e., $\boldsymbol{x}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_{2}$ into $\boldsymbol{X}$ and formulate a new data matrix $\widehat{\boldsymbol{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N+2) \times D}$. The two outliers satisfy that $\left\|\boldsymbol{x}_{1}\right\|_{2}=\left\|\boldsymbol{x}_{2}\right\|_{2}=1$. Try to ensure $\widehat{\boldsymbol{X}}$ to be a zero-mean data matrix and maximize the difference between its covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{\widehat{\boldsymbol{X}}}$ and the original $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{\boldsymbol{X}}$, i.e., $\max \left\|\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{\widehat{\boldsymbol{X}}}-\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right\|_{F}^{2}$.

What I've thought about is:

The zero-mean condition force $\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}$ to be:
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}^{T}=\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{T}, \boldsymbol{x}^{T},-\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right)
$$
and we know that
$$
\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}=1
$$
We conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma_{\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}} &=\frac{1}{N+1} \hat{\boldsymbol{X}}^{T} \hat{\boldsymbol{X}} \\
&=\frac{1}{N+1}\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{X}+2 \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{N+1}\left[(N-1) \Gamma \boldsymbol{X}+2 \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\|\Gamma_{\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right\|_{F}^{2} &=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\|\Gamma_{\hat{\boldsymbol{X}}}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right\|_{F}^{2} \\
&=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\|\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right\|_{F}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

In fact, for the symmetry of $\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}$, we know

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\|\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right\|_{F}^{2} \\
=&\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right)^{T}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}-\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right)\right)\right\} \\
=&\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right)-\operatorname{tr}\left(\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right)-\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right)\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right)-\operatorname{tr}\left(\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}\right)-\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}\right)\right\} \\
&=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{x}^{T}}\right)-2 \operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right)\right\} \\
&=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \max }\left\{1-2 \operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right)\right\} \\
&=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \min }\left\{\boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
Because $\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}$ is positive definite, apply EVD to $\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}$
$$
\Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}}=\boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{V}^{T}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{V}^{T}=\boldsymbol{I}
$$
So
$$
\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \min }\left\{\boldsymbol{x} \Gamma_{\boldsymbol{X}} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right\}=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \min }\left\{\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{V}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right\}
$$
Let
$$
y=x V
$$
We know that
$$
\|\boldsymbol{y}\|_{2}^{2}=\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{y}^{T}=\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{V}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}=1
$$

Let $\sigma$ be the smallest eigenvalues in $\Lambda$, finally we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\underset{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \min }\left\{\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{V} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{V}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}\right\} &=\underset{\|\boldsymbol{y}\|_{2}=1}{\arg \min }\left\{\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{y}^{T}\right\} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_{i} \boldsymbol{y}_{i}^{2} \\
& \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma \boldsymbol{y}_{i}^{2} \\
&=\sigma
\end{aligned}
$$
Assuming that $\sigma=\lambda_{k}$, the optimal solution is:

$$
\boldsymbol{y}= \begin{cases}1 & i=k \\ 0 & i \neq k\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}=\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{V}^{T}
$$

So, maybe you could simplify your optimization object through the 2-norm=1 of $\boldsymbol{x}$ or convert the core to the trace..?